# $\Delta$ operator is it as a differential operator?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, education, alternative-proof

Consider the second law of dynamics written in terms of both momentum, momentum of a force and angular momentum,

$$\bbox[5px,border:3px solid #F5B041]{\overline{F}=\frac{\Delta\overline{p}}{\Delta t}} \tag 1$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:3px solid #A2B151]{\overline{M}=\frac{\Delta\overline{L}}{\Delta t}} \tag 2$$

In the proof of the $(2)$ we use the concept of $\overline{L}=\overline r \times \overline p$ where $\overline r$ it is the position vector and the $\overline{p}$ it is the momentum.

$$\Delta \overline L=\Delta (\overline r \times \overline p)$$

If I consider $\Delta$ as $d$ (*differential operator*) I know that using the calculus I will obtain$$\bbox[lightgray,5px,border:2px solid teal]{d(\overline r \times \overline p)=(d\overline r)\times \overline p \, + \,\overline r\times (d\overline p)} $$

In my textbook of Physics I have:
$$\bbox[orange,5px,border:2px solid gray]{\Delta(\overline r \times \overline p)=(\Delta\overline r)\times \overline p \, + \,\overline r\times (\Delta\overline p)} \tag 4$$

> Because the operator $\Delta$ must have the same role as the differential operator $d$? Does $\Delta$ a laplacian operator? Is it possible to proof the $(4)$ without the calculus?

PS: My students, still they not use the calculus (derivates).

Comment: Looks like $\Delta$ is probably a finite change, in which case it behaves like $d$ from calculus, provided the rate of change doesn't change on the time interval in question.

Comment: @Ian Hi and +1 for the comment. I thought the same thing, too. But $d(f(x))=f'(x) \cdot dx$ but with $\Delta$ I have not an increment similar to $dx$.

Comment: You do: for example, $\Delta \vec {p}=\vec{F} \cdot \Delta t$, which is correct even on finite time intervals provided you keep the force constant the whole time.

Comment: @Downvoter: What is the reason of the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - here, $\Delta$ is certainly not the "Laplacian" operator!

[In the following, I'm not decorating vectors with overlines for reasons of laziness.]

In any event:  $\Delta (r\times p)$ equals, the first line by definition, and the next line by expanding out the terms in the cross product,
$$ \begin{align}\Delta (r\times p) &= (r+\Delta r ) \times (p+\Delta p) - r\times p\\&= r\times p + (r \times \Delta p) + (\Delta r \times p) + (\Delta r \times \Delta p)- r\times p.\end{align}  $$
Canceling (subtraction) the two $r\times p$ terms, on gets

$$ \Delta (r\times p) = (r \times \Delta p) + (\Delta r \times p) + (\Delta r \times \Delta p). $$

The above is almost a tautology...

Now, if, in your case, $\Delta r \times \Delta p =0$  [which is possible!], then

$$ \Delta (r\times p) = (r \times \Delta p) + (\Delta r \times p).$$

Otherwise, under the assumption that $(\Delta r \times \Delta p)$ is small compared to the other terms, one "only" has that

$$ \Delta (r\times p) \approx (r \times \Delta p) + (\Delta r \times p).$$

In that case, your text is at best taking a liberty in writing $=$ instead of $\approx$ [unless of course $\Delta r \times \Delta p =0$ in your case]. I am not sure that I approve! On the other hand, I have read an equation of Fermi which ended up equating an irrational number ($\pi$, say) to a rational number  ($3.1$, say) - and Fermi certainly knew what he was doing...  Fermi was only interested in maintaining accuracy of to $0.1$ (say)... For instance $ 5\times 0.1 + 0.1\times 10 = 1.5 $ is much bigger than $0.1\times 0.1 = 0.01$, which one might legitimately 'neglect'. But bear in mind what you mean.

I hope this helps...

Comment: I thank all the users and even you for your patience. Basically for me it is a good answer. And good thing that some votes (I generally vote positive) has remained :-)

Comment: As I said, I do hope it helps... [please note I corrected a typo from a previous iteration].

Comment: Please, can you explain better $\Delta (r\times p) = (r+\Delta r ) \times (p+\Delta p) - r\times p= (r \times \Delta p) + (\Delta r \times p) + (\Delta r \times \Delta p)$? (the last identity)

Comment: I added a bit more... See edit!

Comment: Thank you very much....approved!!!!!!! :-)